# MonkeyTalkIDE not found Java (JRE) / (JDK) virtual machine

Tags: android-monkey

I am trying to install MonkeyTalkIDE but show this error

A java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development kit (JDK) must be available in order to run MonkeyTalkIDE. No Java virtual machine was found after searching the following locations: C:\Program Files\MonkeyTalkIDE\jre\bin\javaw.exe javaw.exe in your current PATH.

I am also set environment variable for java.

How can resolved problem?

Answer (score 0):

Download a Java JDK [here](http://java.com/en/download/index.jsp).

You might need to set JAVA_HOME to point to the directory where you install Java.   (I'll assume you know how to do that.)

```
set JAVA_HOME=<directory-where-you-installed-JDK>
```

Add the path to the Java /bin directory to your PATH environment variable.  (I'll assume you know how to do that.)  If you do the second step, it'll be

```
PATH=%PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;
```